# Query the first object of all user related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a django model like below:

```py
class Books:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I already have like a million entries in the `Books` table and added `first` field recently. Now I want to update the `first` field of the first created object of every user to True.

```py
all = Books.objects.all()
li = []
for i in all:
   if i.user.username not in li:
       i.first = True
       i.save()
       li.append(i.user.username)
```

I tried the following function but it takes so long to execute, with much data in it. So is there a faster way? Tried the `bulk_update` method, for that also the loop should be completed.

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes. I use PostgreSQL for production and sqlite for development

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using PostgreSQL you can call .distinct() on specific column, and after that use queryset .update() method to update all columns to same value which should be a lof faster.

```
Books.objects.all().order_by('timeStamp').distinct('author').update(first=True)
```

Code above first orders queryset by `timeStamp` field, after that calling distinct on author column leaving only first distinct row (earliest) and in the end updates column value.

Comment: I'm marking this a the answer but there's a correction to be made. `distinct` method followed by `order_by` will work only if the data is ordered by the related table (here User). So the code will look like `Books.objects.all().order_by('author_id').distinct('author').update(first=True)`. Please note that `timeStamp` is not editable after creation so I can use `id` instead of `timeStamp` which I originally asked! Thanks a lot. Appreciated if the answer is updated!

Comment: Also, The above solution is only possible with MariaDB and MySQL while chaining `order_by` with `update`, so my query will be ignored and all the field values will be updated regardless of the filter applied. So for now I have much shorter queryset and can apply my function without any issue, though there's no faster solution. [link] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#ordered-queryset

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Could you unmark this answer as accepted as it may be harmful if someone copies this code and accidentally destroys table in DB?

Comment: @Mowlisri it will work Fine with Postgres as well